# Where can I find examples of functional specifications?

Tags: specifications, writing

I am writing a functional specification for a software program (Mac OS X application to be exact). I want to improve this by looking at other (good) functional specifications, but I cannot find any.

Are there any (open-source) projects that have their specs publicly available so I can learn from them and improve my spec writing skills?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at the work of Karl Wiegers. His [Process Impact site has a Goodies page](http://www.processimpact.com/goodies.shtml) that includes numerous sample documentation and documentation templates. I'd also highly suggest his books, [Software Requirements](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735618798) and [More About Software Requirements](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735622671), which include more information about all aspects of requirements engineering and provide samples and examples.

Answer (score 0):

It may not look like a traditional software spec, but see:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec

These are specs which also act as documentation and executable tests.

Note however, most successful is not created with a large detailed spec written up-front. The common alternative is an agile, iterative process.